# Read Turkish Character from Excel in Java

Tags: java, utf, import-from-excel

I have a script that reads rows from Excel and writes to my DB (PostgreSQL). Everything is OK but there are some problems when sentences include Turkish characters (`ç`, `ü`, `ğ` etc). Some of these sentences work fine and some don't. Examples:

`Çocuklar şu anda parkta` (in Excel) -> `Çocuklar şu anda parkta` (in Java) is not problem

`Sue evli ve iki çocuklu` (in Excel) -> `Sue evli ve iki �ocuklu` (in Java) is problem

Both of them include that `ç`.

How I can convert true format?

Comment: Its probably an encoding issue, can you provide the code that you use to read in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WorkbookSettings workbookSettings = new WorkbookSettings();
workbookSettings.setEncoding( "Cp1252" );//or other encoding
Workbook.getWorkbook( theFile, workbookSettings );
```

Comment: File ExcelFile = new File(this.path);
   
   WorkbookSettings workbookSettings = new WorkbookSettings();
   workbookSettings.setEncoding( "Cp1252" );//or other encoding
   Workbook.getWorkbook( ExcelFile, workbookSettings );

   Workbook wb = Workbook.getWorkbook(ExcelFile);

   Sheet ExcelSheet = wb.getSheet(0);




the problem is still not resolved

Comment: You could try "ISO-8859-3".

Comment: WorkbookSettings workbookSettings = new WorkbookSettings();
   workbookSettings.setEncoding( "ISO-8859-3" );
   Workbook wb = Workbook.getWorkbook(ExcelFile,workbookSettings);

That's OK;)Thanks